# evaluate a double integral $\int_D (x^2+y^2)$ in $D$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Use change of variables to compute $\int_D (x^2+y^2)$, where $D$ is the region in the first quadrant between the hyperbolas $xy=1, xy=2, x^2-y^2=1, x^2-y^2=4$.

Can anyone give me a hint about how to choose the new variables?

I tried $u=x^2, v=y^2$, but it did not seem to work.

Comment: Try $xy=u$ and $x^2-y^2=v$

Comment: Then, it becomes $\int_D \frac{v^2}{v+2u} - 2u$, and $D: 1\le u\le 2, 1\le v\le 4$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn But I did not feel easier to compute... did anything went wrong for me?

Comment: @R.T. $$x^2+y^2=\sqrt{x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4}=\sqrt{x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4+4x^2y^2}=\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}=\sqrt{v^2+4u^2}$$

Comment: I don't see how you would get this. Did you calculate the Jacobian?

Comment: @JohnDoe $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = \frac{1}{-2y^2-2x^2}$, is that right?

Comment: @R.T. Even if that is correct, its simpler to calculate $\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}$, and this is what you need

Comment: Oh, then the integral becomes $\int_D \frac{1}{2}$, with $D$ above?

Comment: I do not see why I need the Jocobian, I thought I need the inverse of Jacobian for the change of variable.

Comment: @R.T. You want to write $dx \ dy = \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} du \ dv$

Comment: @KennyWong Yep, I think this is the inverse of Jacobian...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really meant to be a comment rather than an answer. When doing these sorts of questions, I think it's good to visualise what you're doing, rather than trying to compute blindly. This is not just extra amusement - it's actually important that we verify that our new coordinates parametrise the integration domain in a one-to-one matter.

So I've plotted lines of constant $u = xy$ for various values of $u \in [1,2]$ (purple), and lines of constant $v = x^2 - y^2$ for various values of $v \in [1,4]$ (blue). I don't know what those straight grey lines are - that's just what Mathematica produced!

Anyway, your integration domain is where the blue and purple lines intersect. You can see from the picture that your $u$ and $v$ coordinates parametrise your domain in a one-to-one manner.

[image]

For the purposes of the doing the computation, you want to change variables by writing
$$ dx \ dy = \left| \det \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right| du \ dv$$

But in this particular example, it's actually easier to compute
$$ du \ dv = \left| \det \frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right| dx \ dy  = (x^2 + y^2) \ dx \ dy $$
(You should check the algebra! You should also think about why the determinant turned out to be negative in this case...)

Since the original integral includes a factor of $x^2 + y^2$ in the integrand, this is very convenient! I'll let you finish off from here.